# Can't save file in Spyder using Anaconda on Windows

Tags: python, windows, spyder, anaconda3

I'm guessing this has something to do with a windows update (can't figure out what else might have caused it). I am suddenly not able to save a file, "Save" and "Save all" is now grayed out (See picture bellow) and CTRL+S doesn't work anymore. I am however able to use "Save as" to over write the existing file, which is very strange since you would think that write protection would prevent that. Does anyone know what's going on or how to fix it? I'm using the latest version of Anaconda (tried reinstalling, same issue). Everyone else I read about isn't able to save files at all, while I am still able to use "Save as", I don't appear to have any ransomware protection enabled (that I can find).

[image]

Comment: Also having troubles with this, on MacOS, on Spyder 5.0.5....